# Capacitors in RFID reader

Tags: capacitor, components, rfid, symbol

I'm trying to understand [a schematic of an RFID reader](http://arduino.cc/playground/Main/DIYRFIDReader).

Circuit:
[image: RFID erader]

What capacitors are used - electrolytic or ceramic capacitors?

I've seen schemes of RFID readers that use electrolytic capacitors, but in this scheme I can't see the "+" side of any capacitors.

Comment: Those capacitors are small, so, you will not even find electrolytic capacitors with those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would venture an educated guess that these are ceramic capacitors.

- It's extremely unlikely that capacitors below 1 microfarad (in general) are electrolytic
- The symbols in the schematic also imply non-polarized capacitors
- C3 and C5 are used for coupling, which isn't a good (or safe) use for polarized electrolytic capacitors

Answer (score 2):

I think there are ceramic capacitors, for they are small in capacity.

Comment: I completely disagree.

Comment: @Madmanguruman, sorry! I have typed the wrong key word! forgive me!!

Comment: You corrected your answer, which is the most important thing.